# contains with collator

Tags: java, contains

I have to test whether a string is included in another one but without considering case or accents (French accents in this case).

For example the function must return `true` if I search for `"rhone"` in the string `"Vallée du Rhône"`.

The Collator is useful for string comparison with accents but does not provide a `contains` function.

Is there an easy way to do the job ? A regex maybe ?

*Additional information :*
I just need a `true` / `false` return value, I don't care about number of matches or position of the test string in the reference string.

Comment: Unfortunately, java.util.regex does not support collating sequences, otherwise you could have indeed tried and match against `\brh[[=o=]]ne\b`...

Answer (score 21, accepted):

You can use [Normalizer](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/Normalizer.html) to reduce strings to stripped-down versions that you can compare directly.

**Edit:** to be clear

```
String normalized = Normalizer.normalize(text, Normalizer.Form.NFD);
String ascii = normalized.replaceAll("[^\\p{ASCII}]", "");
```

Answer (score 15):

Have a look at [Normalizer](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/text/Normalizer.html).

You should call it with `Normalizer.Form.NFD` as your second argument.

So, that would be:

```
Normalizer.normalize(yourinput, Normalizer.Form.NFD)
    .replaceAll("\\p{InCombiningDiacriticalMarks}+", "")
    .toLowerCase()
    .contains(yoursearchstring)
```

which will return true if match (and, of course, false otherwise)

Comment: Won't this decompose 'è' to 'e`'? That would make contain() fail unless accented chars are always the last one of the string.

Answer (score 4):

How about this?

```
private static final Pattern ACCENTS_PATTERN = Pattern.compile("\\p{InCombiningDiacriticalMarks}+");

public static boolean containsIgnoreCaseAndAccents(String haystack, String needle) {
    final String hsToCompare = removeAccents(haystack).toLowerCase();
    final String nToCompare = removeAccents(needle).toLowerCase();

    return hsToCompare.contains(nToCompare);
}

public static String removeAccents(String string) {
    return ACCENTS_PATTERN.matcher(Normalizer.normalize(string, Normalizer.Form.NFD)).replaceAll("");
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.out.println(removeAccents("Vallée du Rhône"));
    System.out.println(removeAccents("rhone"));
    System.out.println(containsIgnoreCaseAndAccents("Vallée du Rhône", "rhone"));

}
```

Answer (score 0):

The normal way to do this is to convert both strings to lowercase without accents, and then use the standard 'contains'.